# Which is best practice doing null checks or empty checks with Kotlin data classes?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I am fetching data from server and creating  api data layer then mapping this api data layer to ui data layer some of fields should not be neighter null  nor empty if I get null/empty I should not continue further actions
my question

```
class ApiPerson(name:String?, surname:String?,properties:List<Property>)

data class Person(name:String,surname:String)
```

so should I map like this

```
fun ApiPerson.toUIModel():Person{
Person(this.name?:"",this.surname?:"",emptyList())
}
```

and when using the object check if it empty or not.
or should I let presenter model accept null values like
Person(this.name?:null,this,surname?:null,null)
and when using object do null checks with ? or let operator istead of empty() checks
Or should I have requireNotNull() usage or what? 
Which is the best practice?
I like the idea of emptycheck if it list but with string I prefer doing ? null checks. I would like to know the best practice

Comment: If fields should not be null then why make them nullable fields?

Comment: If the server sends you null for a field that should never be null - it should be a hard crash on the client. Second-guessing the server is a bad strategy that can get your app into a bad state.

Comment: Also, there is `.orEmpty()`.